# Resolve Addresses To Function Names

Tags: ida, malware, idapython, windbg, dynamic-linking

I have a malware sample that wraps `LoadLibrary` & `GetProcAddress` duo to dynamically resolve functions. After this wrapper is called the value stored in `eax`(which is the function name)immediately gets called. The strings are encrypted and it's too difficult for me to reverse the encryption algorithm. Instead I wrote a python script which sets breakpoints where a `call eax` instruction is mentioned. Everyting's fine, I get the addresses of the functions from `eax` that are dynamically imported. The problem is I need them to be readable. I know how to resolve the address to a function name in widbg by calling `ln address`. But I don't want to sit all day and copy all of the 649 imports one by one to the `windbg` console. I looked up the `windbg`'s scripting capabilities but I could not write anything that would do the job.

Thanks

Comment: `I looked up the windbg's scripting capabilities but I could not write anything that would do the job.` you can use python with windbg through [pykd](https://pykd.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i dont know if i understood your query correctly but if you want to log the function names that are passed to getproc address you can log them like this in windbg

```
C:\>cdb calc

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.15063.468 X86

ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
775605a6 cc              int     3

0:000> bp KERNELBASE!GetProcAddress ".printf \"%ma\\n\",poi(@esp+8);gc"

0:000> bl
 0 e 756c6c81     0001 (0001)  0:**** KERNELBASE!GetProcAddress ".printf \"%ma\\n\",poi(@esp+8);gc"


0:000> g

ImmWINNLSEnableIME
ImmWINNLSGetEnableStatus
ImmSendIMEMessageExW
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
CtfImmTIMActivate
CtfImmRestoreToolbarWnd
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
LpkPSMTextOut
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ModLoad: 740c0000 740d3000   C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
DwmIsCompositionEnabled
GetLayout
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ModLoad: 75590000 7559c000   C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
SystemFunction036
CLSIDFromOle1Class
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ModLoad: 73b70000 73bac000   C:\Windows\system32\oleacc.dll
EventWrite
EventRegister
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BufferedPaintStopAllAnimations

ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
774f4108 cc              int     3
0:004> q
quit:

C:\>
```

afaik windbg also resolves the address to its function Name

```
0:000> rM0
calc!WinMain+0x6b:
001316a0 ffd7            call    edi {kernel32!GetModuleHandleWStub (7737ccac)}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to know specifically how to resolve the value `eax` holds to a function name. IDA does it for instance if there address like 0x77****** IDA shows what function that is.

Comment: windbg as far as i know also resolves the address to function names see the edit

Comment: I am aware of that. I want windbg to do that for all of the 649 addresses and I don't want to do that manually. Also I don't know if that's possible with idapython.

Comment: your query is still unclear you have to set breakpoint on all call eax to do that you need to pattern match and collect the addresses for pattern matching you can use # call*eax  range then use .foreach on the results   there is no arbitrary way in any debugger to break on  call eax automatically you either need to step each instruction or preset bps based on some manual work if you know getproc address is called each time your best bet is to grab it there

Comment: found out that windbg has .for loops and it did the job Thanks. Your answer was helpful.